# Clean with eclipse but cannot compile Helloworld in terminal (Error: Could not find or load main class)

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, terminal

I'm trying to compile in the terminal (Fedora) my package I've written in eclipse. 
I need to turn these .java's into my teach for homework but after I compile them in a .class file they will not execute with java DoThisDamnit.java.

```
root@localhost mypackage# javac -cp . DoThisDamnit.java
root@localhost mypackage# ls
DoThisDamnit.class  DoThisDamnit.java
root@localhost mypackage# java DoThisDamnit.java
Error: Could not find or load main class DoThisDamnit.java
```

What I have done is the following:

- Created a Project name: My Project
- Created a Package name: mypackage
- Created a class file:   DoThisDamnit

After I clean the file it is exported to /home/william/workspace/bin or src. When I go to the bin and type

```
Java DoThisDamnit.class
```

I get the error *Error: could not find or load main class*

I have a feeling I'm not running it correctly since it has a package?

Code test

```
package mypackage;

public class DoThisDamnit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Doooo it");
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive my code input.. it wouldn't let me post and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Post your code, I'll edit it in order to get seen by other people.

Comment: did you try `java DoThis`? Could you post us the code of `DoThis.java`?

Comment: How come you compiled DoThis.java and ended up with DoThisDamnit.class? The java command doesn't require the extension, just the class name e.g. `java DoThis`.

Comment: By the way, it looks like you need `public static void main(String[] args)` method in your `DoThisDamnit` class.

Comment: I had badwords which I was trying to take out for the post. This is basically "Hello world" within a package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run :

```
cd <your folder> ///home/william/workspace/bin
java mypackage.DoThisDamnit
```

Comment: Or stay in the same folder and type `java -cp ./.. mypackage.DoThisDamnit`

Comment: This was it! You rock.. I've been trying to do this since 4PM even my teacher was puzzled. (Hes not linux I think) so it threw everything off.

Answer (score 0):

When I've had this error, it's because my class, in your case DoThis, did not have a main method.

Comment: package mypackage;

public class DoThisDamnit {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.print("Doooo it");

 }

}

Comment: But you aren't writing 'java DoThisDamnit'.  It's looking for main in DoThis.

Comment: The public static void main(String[] args) is my main method?

Comment: Yeah, but you have the java interpreter has to run the class that has the main method.  So, 'java DoThisDamnit' should work if DoThisDamnit.class exists in the directory.  But does class DoThis also hava a main?